# Listagem de dados MYSQL VIEW

Tags: mysql, count

Eu fiz uma view que me lista uma contagem de registro em Dia, Semana, Mês e Ano, mas quando eu adiciono novos registros os registro de Dia não muda somente os demais.

Segue o código do dia:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas` WHERE funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m-%d'), funcionario_id limit 1
```

segue todos os códigos juntos:

```
SELECT
    distinct
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas` WHERE funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m-%d'), funcionario_id limit 1) as dia,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas` WHERE  funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id and inicio BETWEEN DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL(1 - DAYOFWEEK(now())) DAY)  AND DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL(3 + DAYOFWEEK(now())) DAY) GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%u') limit 1) as semana,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas` WHERE funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m'), funcionario_id limit 1) as mes,
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas` WHERE funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%Y'), funcionario_id limit 1) as ano,
    (select users.name from users,funcionarios where funcionarios.id = agendas.funcionario_id and users.id = funcionarios.user_id) as nome
from
    agendas
```

Para que fiz mais explicativo o retorno da view

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retorno sem a view somente dos dias

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você **não está especificando o dia que quer consultar**, sua consulta para o dia está limitando sempre ao primeiro dia retornado como resultado, que no caso é 2019-07-15. Não tenho como testar agora a minha solução proposta, mas eu aconselharia a trocar sua consulta do dia para:

```
// Caso você queira a consulta do dia corrente
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas`
WHERE funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id
-- AQUI INDICO QUE QUERO SOMENTE OS RESULTADOS QUE SÃO IGUAIS A DATA ATUAL DO SISTEMA 
AND date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m-%d'), funcionario_id limit 1
```

Ou então:

```
// Caso você queira a consulta do último dia que sem tem registro
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `agendas`
WHERE funcionario_id = agendas.funcionario_id
GROUP BY date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m-%d'), funcionario_id
-- AQUI ORDENO OS RESULTADOS DE FORMA DECRESCENTE
ORDER BY date_format(inicio, '%Y-%m-%d') DESC
limit 1
```

Comment: Te dei ponto de resolvido, mas já tinha resolvido fazendo uma procedure passando a data que irei validar.